# ui grid save updated cell data to database

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am working on ui grid edit cell feature. I need to update the edited cell value to the database using rest api. Also how can i get the list of rows selected in controller.

My working code

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.edit']);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
      $scope.gridOptions = {  };

      $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
        { name: 'id', enableCellEdit: false},
        { name: 'name' },
        { name: 'age', displayName: 'Age' , type: 'number', width: '10%' }
      ];


      $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/500_complex.json')
        .success(function(data) {
          $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
        });
    }])
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kAQnXGTn12Z7v8w16RL9?p=preview)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add the following to your controller:

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi) {
  //set gridApi on scope
  $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
  gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope, function(rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue) {
    //Do your REST call here via $http.get or $http.post

    //Alert to show what info about the edit is available
    alert('Column: ' + colDef.name + ' ID: ' + rowEntity.id + ' Name: ' + rowEntity.name + ' Age: ' + rowEntity.age);
  });
};
```

You have all the information about which column was edited (in `colDef.name`) and what the actual values of the cells are (in `rowEntity.xxx`).

All you have to do now is call your REST API (to avoid unnecessary traffic, you could also compare `newValue` to `oldValue` to see if the content really was changed).

You don't need to reload the data, because the changes are already applied to the scope.

Find a [forked Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VdmvcOptoP5LC5VSyY9L?p=preview) here.

Second part of your question:

None of your rows are selectable. And this may get a bit complicated. Please start a new Question (with a new Plunker) about this issue.

Comment: Seems to still work correctly with ui-grid 4.x! Thanks! This isn't well documented anywhere I could find.