# How to change the cell's background color of the ui-grid to some color, if its edited and new value is not equal to the old value (dirty).

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

Based on this [help link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28920028/detect-cell-edit-in-angular-ui-grid) I was able to achieve color change but in this solution it applies the color to the entire row, that is not I'm looking for.

I want to change the color of the only edited cell. Please share if anybody has some idea. Thanks.

Comment: Put some code in your question, show what have you done so far.

Comment: @AnandGhaywankar It took a while to create a Plunker for this, and here it is [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/WiIo7Dddxh52uloTtWTW?p=preview), sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a plunker example with your desired behaviour: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZfeiNxiGLqeivFeaqY2y?p=preview

The code block of interest is:

```
gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope, function(rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue) {

colDef.cellClass = function(grid, row, col, rowRenderIndex, colRenderIndex) {
      if (rowEntity.id === row.entity.id && newValue !== oldValue) {
        return "test" ;
      }
      return "";
    };

$scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN);
```

Note that "test" is the class name defined in main.css

```
.test {
 background-color: red !important
}
```

**EDIT**: Here is a fork of your plunker example: http://plnkr.co/edit/OgecJQo8FOREIsQcufuz?p=preview

Comment: Yeah thanks for your time this solution is works fine, but this is not the only scenario I'm looking for. pleas refer the plunker i have created may be you can get some idea what i exactly looking for. [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/WiIo7Dddxh52uloTtWTW?p=preview)

Comment: Looks fine, and almost near. but one catch is, in a row if multiple cells are edited and dirty, its showing only one cell as yellow. I want to show each and every edited cells as yellow. 

may be I'll explore on that. thanks much for your time and appreciate you work.

Comment: updated my [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WiIo7Dddxh52uloTtWTW?p=preview). now its working as expected for me. Thanks.

Comment: @AlinPandichi concerning the first [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZfeiNxiGLqeivFeaqY2y?p=preview) is it possible to keep all updated cell colored? I mean that the actual behavior is that only one sel is colored, when we update another one, the first one will change back to the normal color, but I need to keep them both colored.

Comment: @MohamedNAOUALI Assuming I understood correctly what you are trying to do, I have created a new plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/eWa6moRWEdj6Svvgot40?p=preview
But please be aware that the code is just a quick hack. I recommend that you take a good look at the documentation, try to understand how the code works, and then adjust it to better fit your needs.

Comment: If I Rollback the changes in the column i.e, the column value is same as initial value, is there a way to remove the background color ?